# How to distort a letter into a triangular shape on illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, distort

I've tried making a triangle shape while selecting my letter and going to envelope distort > make with top object and this is what I got...

[image]

Comment: To do it effectively, you need to create outlines and **manually** move anchors and paths.

Answer (score 1):

What about using Make with Warp, and the "Arc" style, then modifying it by editing the nodes and curves of the warp? Although to be honest, it might take just as long as drawing the outlines manually from scratch.

I tried it, and it involved quite a bit of messing around for a less than perfect result. Obviously if you have more time to spend tweaking . . . then go for it!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh` and enter just 1 row and 1 column....

[image]

(I have a guide set up for the desired shape)

Then with the envelope in place, you can merely move it's corners and handles to distort the letter. This will often get you close, but possibly not exact.

[image]

Another option is to create outlines of the type (Type > Create Outlines), and then move the anchors, paths , and handles on the letter itself. This takes more work but can offer a great deal more control.

Here's a quick and dirty attempt:

[image]

In any event, *some* manual alteration is going to be required. There's really nothing in Illustrator which will distort to match a specific shape every time for every shape.